# Remote event receiver for host web returns null

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have the following issue. I 've developed a provider hosted app with remote event receivers. I can access content on the app (lists created in the app) and also office 365 properties.

But i want to access a list created on host web.

On edit of an item, i want to add that item into a calendar on host web.

I use this code :

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = /*clientContextTest*/TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(propertiesFunction,false))
        {

            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                List calendarList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LeaveCalendar");

                clientContext.Load(calendarList);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                ListItemCreationInformation calendaritemCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

                ListItem calendarItem = calendarList.AddItem(calendaritemCreationInfo);

                calendarItem["Title"] = "Leave Request for " + requesterName + " for " + Convert.ToString(workDaysRequested) + " day(s)";
                calendarItem["EventDate"] = startDate;
                calendarItem["EndDate"] = endDate;
                calendarItem.Update();

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
```

However the client context returns null. I used the CreateAppEventClientContext because is the one specified to access host web content.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Remote Event Receiver for List on Host Web, the following articles for your reference:

Attaching Remote Event Receivers to Lists in the Host Web

[Attaching Remote Event Receivers to Lists in the Host Web](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/)

Remote Event Receiver (RER) for Host Web using SharePoint Provider Hosted App in Office 365/SharePoint Online Environment

[Remote Event Receiver (RER) for Host Web using SharePoint Provider Hosted App](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/)